# C programm by Valgrind check: can't return all the reserved storage space

Tags: c, arrays, string, memory-management, valgrind

I have the following code for output a txt file from a csv file using strings and array, and the library "input3.h" is a code for output files to TXT.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "input3.h"

/* Die Konstanten:
 *  int MAX_LAENGE_STR - die maximale String LÃ¤nge
 *  int MAX_LAENGE_ARR - die maximale Array LÃ¤nge
 *  sind input3.c auf jeweils 255 und 100 definiert
 */

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    if (argc < 3) {
        printf("Aufruf: %s <anzahl> <bundesland>\n", argv[0]);
        printf("Beispiel: %s 100 Bayern\n", argv[0]);
        printf("Klein-/GroÃŸschreibung beachten!\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    int anzahl = atoi(argv[1]);
    char *bundesland = argv[2];

    // Statisch allokierter Speicher
    char staedte[MAX_LAENGE_ARR][MAX_LAENGE_STR];
    char laender[MAX_LAENGE_ARR][MAX_LAENGE_STR];
    int bewohner[MAX_LAENGE_ARR];

    int len = read_file("staedte.csv", staedte, laender, bewohner);

    // Hier implementieren
    char ** jg;
    int cc = 0;
    int cc_jg = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        if((strcmp(bundesland, laender[i]) == 0) && (bewohner[i] >= anzahl)) {
            cc ++;
        }
    }

    jg = (char **) malloc(MAX_LAENGE_ARR*sizeof(char *));;
    for (int j = 0; j < len; j++) {
        jg[j] = (char*)malloc(MAX_LAENGE_STR*sizeof(char));
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        if((strcmp(bundesland, laender[i]) == 0) && (bewohner[i] >= anzahl)) {
            sprintf(jg[cc_jg], "Die Stadt %s hat %d Einwohner.", staedte[i], bewohner[i]);
            cc_jg++;
        }
    }

// Mithilfe von write_file(...) soll das Ergebnis in die "resultat.txt"
    write_file(jg, cc_jg);

    // Dynamisch allozierter Speicher muss hier freigegeben werden.
    for(int l = 0; l < cc; l++) {
        free(jg[l]);
    }
    free(jg);
    return 0;
}
```

My problem it that if this programm checked by Valgrind, it said that this programm can't return all the reserved storage space, and I don't understand why does this problem excist.

Comment: That's not a [Minimal, **Complete**, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). What is `MAX_LAENGE_ARR`? What is `MAX_LAENGE_STR`? How are they defined? What are their values?

Comment: You allocate `len` pointers but only free `cc` pointers.

Comment: They are defined as the maximal length of the string and array.  the value for  `MAX_LAENGE_STR` is 255 and `MAX_LAENGE_ARR` is 100.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You run the malloc for `jg[j]` `len` times, but only free it `cc` times.

Correctly you would do:

```
for(int l = 0; l < len; l++) {
        free(jg[l]);
    }
```